# Scrollbar button size in internet explorer 8 to 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I've got a really small scroll-able table which shows scroll buttons and scroll-bar just fine in older IEs, but IE11 has problems, because up/down buttons are so large that they somehow overlap and user cannot even press the "down" button let alone grab the scroll indicator - its not even visible. The only option to scroll is via mouse scroll-er or keyboard buttons.

Here is how the problem looks like (IE 8, IE 9, IE 11):

[image: IE 8] [image: IE 9] [image: IE 11]

Is there anyway I can affect scroll-bar button sizes in IE via css/html/JavaScript? Can users change something on their end (besides not using IE11)? Will I have to redesign this part of the page to be bigger?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use: [nanoscroller](https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/), though for best usability I would advise you to make the page height bigger

Comment: This is exactly how I got around the problem, I redid the layout of the page and made scrollable table higher.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your scrollbar and improve your UI design for better useable.
This method also works in the table for design scrollbar and supports all browsers.

```css
.scrollable {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.scrollable-container {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  width: 240px;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.scrollable div {
  font-size: 23px;
  
}

/*IE*/
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
.scrollable {
        margin-right: -10px;
        padding-top: 32px;
        margin-top: -32px;
        margin-bottom: -32px;
        padding-bottom: 32px;

        /* ie scrollbar color properties */
        scrollbar-base-color: #efefef;
        scrollbar-face-color: #666666;
        scrollbar-3dlight-color: #666666;
        scrollbar-highlight-color: #666666;
        scrollbar-track-color: #efefef;
        scrollbar-arrow-color: #666666;
        scrollbar-shadow-color: #666666;
        scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #666666;
  }
  
      .scrollable:after {
        content: "";
        height: 32px;
        display: block;
    }
    
}

/*Edge*/
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto)  {
.scrollable {
        margin-right: -10px;
        padding-top: 16px;
        margin-top: -16px;
        margin-bottom: -16px;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
}
  
.scrollable:after {
    content: "";
    height: 16px;
    display: block;
}
}

/*Firefox*/
/*From version 64 - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/*/
.scrollable {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: #666666 #efefef;
}


/*Chrome*/
.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #efefef;
    width: 4px;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-container">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div>Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```