# How to fix the issue: the scrolling button disappear on Scroll Bar IE11

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

like the tile, I'm dealing with an issue relate to the scrolling button on Scroll bar on IE 11.
I found the question was asked on this link but haven't anyone finds the solution yet.

[Link previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993481/scrollbar-button-size-in-internet-explorer-8-to-11)

here is the screen shot about the issue:

[image: Picture: No scrolling button]

As you can see in the picture, the button will disappear when we decrease the height of the scroll bar. The arrow button is bigger than normal and it overlap the scrolling button.

So, how can we fix it in CSS (bootstrap) or JQuery?

Can we make the arrow buttons smaller like on Chrome and Firefox?

I also found that we can modify some scroll bar properties:

```css
scrollbar-face-color: #000000;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #2D2C4D;
scrollbar-highlight-color:#7D7E94;
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #7D7E94;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #2D2C4D;
scrollbar-track-color: #7D7E94;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #C1C1D1;
```

Hope some help, thanks.